# Why does my Xbox One controller query out to Akamai Technologies when I plug it in?

Tags: tcp

Running wireshark, I've been having issues with my xbox controller I plug into my pc. When I plug it in, it immediately starts some communication with 23.32.109.224. So I firewalled that address out, so that my joystick doesn't query out to microsoft just to start. but if it can query out to that microsoft it can query out to some other later, once they send an update to my driver.

So I have been owned by Microsoft? When I play a game, I have recorded again in wireshark, these umpteen packets that get sent through and make my controller vibrate and go out for a short period of time. Any time this happens, predictable packets come through on wireshark:

```
52.242.101.140 comes in with a TCP  66  63664 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM

52.242.101.140  TLSv1.2 274 Client Hello (SNI=array517.prod.do.dsp.mp.microsoft.com)

78387   362.121935  52.242.101.140  192.168.1.20    TLSv1.2 105 Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
78388   362.121935  52.242.101.140  192.168.1.20    TLSv1.2 123 Application Data
78389   362.121986  192.168.1.20    52.242.101.140  TCP 54  63664 → 443 [ACK] Seq=379 Ack=2552 Win=132352 Len=0
78390   362.122719  192.168.1.20    52.242.101.140  TLSv1.2 141 Application Data
78391   362.122790  192.168.1.20    52.242.101.140  TLSv1.2 204 Application Data
78392   362.122909  192.168.1.20    52.242.101.140  TLSv1.2 92  Application Data
78393   362.122965  192.168.1.20    52.242.101.140  TLSv1.2 703 Application Data

78793   373.674536  23.32.109.224   192.168.1.20    TCP 54  443 → 63669 [RST] Seq=7273 Win=0 Len=0
78794   373.698052  23.32.109.224   192.168.1.20    TCP 54  443 → 63669 [RST] Seq=7745 Win=0 Len=0
78795   373.698052  23.32.109.224   192.168.1.20    TCP 54  443 → 63669 [RST] Seq=7745 Win=0 Len=0
78796   373.701051  23.32.109.224   192.168.1.20    TCP 54  443 → 63669 [RST] Seq=7745 Win=0 Len=0
78797   373.701051  23.32.109.224   192.168.1.20    TCP 54  443 → 63669 [RST] Seq=7746 Win=0 Len=0
78821   373.803626  23.32.109.224   192.168.1.20    TCP 54  443 → 63670 [RST] Seq=1203 Win=0 Len=0
78822   373.803626  23.32.109.224   192.168.1.20    TCP 54  443 → 63670 [RST] Seq=1203 Win=0 Len=0
78823   373.812451  23.32.109.224   192.168.1.20    TCP 54  443 → 63670 [RST] Seq=1676 Win=0 Len=0
78824   373.812451  23.32.109.224   192.168.1.20    TCP 54  443 → 63670 [RST] Seq=1676 Win=0 Len=0
78825   373.821544  23.32.109.224   192.168.1.20    TCP 54  443 → 63670 [RST] Seq=1676 Win=0 Len=0
```

The spamming continues, even a few seconds later,

```
78939   374.316133  23.32.109.224   192.168.1.20    TLSv1.3 78  Application Data
78940   374.316133  23.32.109.224   192.168.1.20    TCP 54  443 → 63674 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1675 Ack=2858 Win=64128 Len=0
78941   374.316230  192.168.1.20    23.32.109.224   TCP 54  63674 → 443 [ACK] Seq=6254 Ack=1676 Win=131328 Len=0
78942   374.316286  192.168.1.20    23.32.109.224   TLSv1.3 78  Application Data
78943   374.316317  192.168.1.20    23.32.109.224   TCP 54  63674 → 443 [FIN, ACK] Seq=6278 Ack=1676 Win=131328 Len=0
78944   374.323247  23.32.109.224   192.168.1.20    TCP 54  443 → 63674 [RST] Seq=1203 Win=0 Len=0
78945   374.324760  23.32.109.224   192.168.1.20    TCP 54  443 → 63674 [RST] Seq=1203 Win=0 Len=0
78946   374.326291  23.32.109.224   192.168.1.20    TCP 54  443 → 63674 [RST] Seq=1203 Win=0 Len=0
78947   374.334315  23.32.109.224   192.168.1.20    TCP 54  443 → 63674 [RST] Seq=1676 Win=0 Len=0
78948   374.334315  23.32.109.224   192.168.1.20    TCP 54  443 → 63674 [RST] Seq=1676 Win=0 Len=0
78949   374.334315  23.32.109.224   192.168.1.20    TCP 54  443 → 63674 [RST] Seq=1676 Win=0 Len=0
78950   375.004727  192.168.1.20    104.172.1.185   UDP 65  2626 → 47981 Len=23
```

I see this line occurring as well:

```
M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\x0d\x0aHOST: 239.255.255.250:1900\x0d\x0aMAN: "ssdp:discover"\x0d\x0aMX: 1\x0d\x0aST: urn:dial-multiscreen-org:service:dial:1\x0d\x0aUSER-AGENT: Microsoft Edge/122.0.2365.92 Windows\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0a"
```

Even firewalling the 23.32.109.224 they can still find a way to send umpteen packets to my router and shut down my controller whenever they want (or so it feels that way, surely it isn't a coincidence as this has been happening to me for some time now)

So my questions are these:

1. Is it obvious based off of what I sent that my network is hacked?
2. How do I prevent this hack from happening?

By the way, this all started happening after I installed a new nvidia graphics card, but I don't think that matters. I think that is unrelated, but I could be wrong.

Let me know please. Thanks

Comment: Network communication you don't **like** does not mean that your system is hacked. There is lots of communication not to like (all the telemetry) but it does not indicate a hack. There are also automatic software and driver updates, which are no hacks either. And the M-SEARCH is [Simple Service Discovery Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol). Basically it looks like that you consider that every communication you don't understand and thus don't expect or which you simply don't like a hacking activity.

Comment: I don't have much experience with game controllers, but I seem to remember they sometines "buzzed" if you did something wrong within the game... are you sure that's not what's happening here?

Comment: Are you sure that 192.168.1.20 is your controller and not your PC? how are you verifying this? If you plug the controller into the PC, how is it getting an IP? "they can still find a way to send umpteen packets to my router" -- no they can't. Your PC (or controller?) connects ***out***.

Comment: You've made quite a few judgement statements here that might be clouding your thinking: "owned by Microsoft", "spamming" "shut down my controller", "hacked". Nothing here suggests anything malicious. And I'm not seeing a ***security*** issue here. This is a product support issue.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft uses Akamai as their CDN (content distribution network) and possibly for other purposes. In particular, Microsoft's updates and downloads are distributed through Akamai. Quite likely what's going on is your PC is seeing you connect a new piece of hardware which it has a driver (but possibly an older driver) for, and is checking to see if there's an update for that driver. This might be either part of the driver-specific functionality, part of the Windows gaming support functionality, or the OS-wide feature to download drivers from the Internet (which goes through Windows Update, but WU packages are distributed through Akamai).

Other things it could be:

- OS Telemetry: by default Windows collects a considerable amount of information about how the computer is used. You can turn some of this off (~all of it, if you use Enterprise or higher editions) but many people don't bother.
- Controller driver or gaming service telemetry: beyond general "how you use the computer" info, Microsoft obviously wants to know how often people use controllers on PC, since this influences business decisions.
- Validation checks: Windows and/or the driver might be querying the Internet to look up information about the controller, such as the certificate/public key that it could use to validate that the hardware is genuine and not a knock-off (I don't know if this is actually a "feature" the controller has, it'd increase the manufacture cost slightly to securely store a private key in each one, but it *could* be done and would likely trigger a lookup at least sometimes).